# В каком файле делать Валидацию

Tags: java, android, валидация

Для отображения в ExpandableListView разметки у меня есть 2 файла:

1) MainActivity:

```
public class BookingActivity extends BaseActivity {

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

int adultCount = 3;
int childCount = 0;
int infCount = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.booking_layout);

    Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mToolbar.setTitle("");
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    mToolbar.setTitle(R.string.booking_title);

    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

}
```

И так далее...

2) ExpandableListAdapter:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

EditText etName;
EditText etLastname;
EditText etBirthday;
AutoCompleteTextView etNationality;
EditText etPassport;
EditText etEmail;
EditText etPhone;
RadioGroup spGender;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

//        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.booking_list_items, null);
    }

    // Get the string array
    countries = convertView.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nation_array);

    etName = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etLastname = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etLastname);
    etBirthday = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etBirthday);
    etNationality = (AutoCompleteTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etNationality);
    etPassport = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etPassport);
    etEmail = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etPhone = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
    spGender = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spGender);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    if (this._listDataChild.containsKey(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)))
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
    else
        return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_headers, null);

    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

**Подскажите, где по вашему опыту лучшу делать валидацию на EditTextы?**

Comment: внутри  if (convertView == null){ здесь}

Comment: Но там не видит мой код:

    `private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {

                String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                        + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";


                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);

                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);

                return matcher.matches();

            }`

Comment: Так перенесите его так, чтобы видело

Comment: metalurgus, вы имеете ввиду if (convertView == null), как, если честно вообще не понимаю, подскажите пожалуйста!